# Forgot password function is not working

Tags: php

Hi in my code everything is correct like query and display conditions but mail sending the message is mail is not send.

Whats the issue in that please find out ..! Mail is not send all the verification is correct why it so please find it only mail is not working or anything issue like headers can you please tell me headers already changed .

```
    <?php
    include '../includes/config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 

        $mail=$_POST['email']; 
     $sql= "select * from users where email= '$mail' ";
      $res = $conn->query($sql);
     $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
     if($num!==0) 
     {

      $rows = $res->fetch_array();

         $to=$rows['email'];
        $subject="Remind password";


      $message ="Your password : ".$rows['encrypted_password'];
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <purendergoud@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

    /* $headers = 'From: purendergoud@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();*/

       if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){



                echo "Message sent successfully...";

        echo'Check your inbox in mail';
       echo "<script>alert('your password sent to your mail');
       window.location('login.php');

    </script>;";
      }
      else
      {
       echo'mail is not send';
      }
     }
     else
     {
      echo'You entered mail id is not present';
     }
    }



?>
```

Comment: Are you storing passwords as plain text in your database?

Comment: no numbers only like the password 123456 it displayed while checking echo correct only

Comment: Are you sure `$to` is a real email? Try `echo 'TO:'.$to;` before `if (mail(...` and see the result. and also try without any headers to see if it's working.

Comment: yes its real email only